# Jena Reasoning and Rule Syntax

Tags: comparison, jena, jena-rules

I have a questions regarding to the Jena API.

I wrote some rules that are working perfectly but with one thing I still have a problem. I hope you can help me with it.

**Comparison of two integer**

In my rules I need a comparison like "GreaterThan". I searched long for it but not a single version worked. I tried `GreaterThan(?x, ?y)` as part of the rule as well as the namespace 
`swrlb:` `<http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#>` with its function 
`swrlb:GreaterEqual`, but both did not worked.

The rule looks like follows:

```
[r0: (?x es:has_intensity ?I), GreaterThan(?I, 2) -> (?x es:test "true")]
```

or my alternative:

```
[r0: (?x es:has_intensity ?I), (?I swrlb:Greater 2) -> (?x es:test "true")]
```

Answer (score 4):

The main issue that you are probably experiencing is that you are not using a known builtin. The builtins are case-sensitive.

As seen in Jena's [`owl-fb.rules`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src/main/resources/etc/owl-fb.rules), the builtin that you intend to use is `greaterThan`, not `GreaterThan`. An example of a rule using the builtin (from `owl-fb.rules`) follows:

```
[validationMaxN: (?v rb:validation on()), (?C rdfs:subClassOf max(?P, ?N)) greaterThan(?N, 1) (?P rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty) ->
    [max2b: (?X rb:violation error('too many values', 'Too many values on max-N property (prop, class)', ?P, ?C))
          <- (?X rdf:type ?C), countLiteralValues(?X, ?P, ?M), lessThan(?N, ?M)  ] ]
```

Editing your rule yields:

```
[r0: (?x es:has_intensity ?I), greaterThan(?I, 2) -> (?x es:test "true")]
```